# React Native: which global packages do you need to keep up-to-date?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

If you're doing React Native development over the course of a few years, which global packages is it important to keep up-to-date? The ones I'm thinking of are Node JS, watchman, cocoapods, and the React Native CLI.

Are there others? Does anyone have tips on how to maintain a React Native development environment over time other than just keeping these packages up-to-date?